# Total Memory size at launch of an asp .dotnet core web-application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory

I have created a web application and functionally it's working fine (both in Dev as well as in Production).

However, what I am confused about is the amount of memory (private byte) allocated at the launch of the program (just the page display - before any button is clicked or any calls are made internally).
**It's showing around 110 MB.** Note that, there is no DB connection / identity etc.

My question is - Is this to be expected?
Right now, my approach is to look for any optimization scope in my code but I can't think of anything to reduce this launch memory.  I have attached a screenshot of the memory profiler tool.

I understand this is a bit vague without an actual piece of code. But the main problem is I am not sure which part of the code is responsible.

Looking for some suggestion on where should I look at to find the issue. Note that I am specifically interested in the launch memory / starting memory.

[image: This is the screenshot of the allocation at the launch]

Comment: 110MB sounds fairly reasonable for a small program. You are probably loading more libraries and other stuff at startup than you are aware of.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I think so too. So if I am expecting 10 concurrent users (max case), and if my program's total memory (private) is around 250 MB, does it mean I should plan for at least 3 GB RAM for this to run smoothly? Is the calculation this simple or am I missing something?

Comment: Your program will need some fixed amount of memory for things like code, runtime etc. As well as some that scale per user. You cannot just multiply the amount of memory needed for one user with ten. If you want to know the memory needed for 10 users, test the system with 10 users.